# Domino SAML Login - access secured resources through API

Tags: saml, lotus-domino, opensso

I have a domino server (v9) with SAML Login enabled through Oracle OpenSSO (and simple login methods disabled, like Basic or Forms).

I can log onto the server using a browser, which does multiple redirects, form submits and so on, to push the SAML token from the Identity Provider to the names.nsf, which then creates a LTPAToken based on the SAML token.

However, I have to access some URLs (API endpoints) programmatically, which are secured by this SAML Login. Does names.nsf allow any API-friendly means of authentication (like Bearer Token) instead, and does OpenSSO support them as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Domino, but for OpenSSO I can say that it embeds a STS (Security Token Service). That means you can request it a SAML Bearer Token.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17842_01/doc.1111/e17844/concepts.htm